# How to slice a 2D tensor using a 1D tensor instead of scalar

Tags: python, pytorch

Normally, you can slice a 2D tensor like this `slice = t[:, :k]` where k is an integer. Is it possible to do something like this but with k being a 1-dimensional vector of integers with the number of items that I want to obtain for each row?

Masking the items with 0's or NaN would also be fine.

For example:

```py
k = torch.Tensor([1,2,3])
t = torch.Tensor([1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3])

# perform some operations and the result should be
# 1 - -
# 2 2 -
# 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to do it by using a mask created by unsqueeze.

```py
k = torch.Tensor([1,3,2])
t = torch.Tensor([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]])
range_tensor = torch.arange(1, t.size(1)+1)

mask = range_tensor > k.unsqueeze(1)
t[mask] = 0 # Or NaN or whatever

# t is now equal to
# tensor([[1., 0., 0.],
#         [2., 2., 2.],
#         [3., 3., 0.]])
```